# Liferay: All languages work when changed in Language portlet except the default one

Tags: properties, liferay, portal

When I select portal default language (DE) english is shown, but for the rest everything is ok. Surprisingly portlets which are i18n'ed work well when change to german, but portal menus are stil in english. If I change to any third language the translation is done correct.

What can I be missing? Where can be the root of the problem? I did not modify (consciently) any portal property file. No Exception is thrown.

Comment: Did you check if the `Language_de.properties` in liferay's source has english or german text?

Comment: I checked and I don't have any Language(-ext).properties at portal level in ROOT folder, and my portal-impl jar shows content/Language_de.properties in german as expected. I'll check per portlet-level one by one. I am in a german VM OS with English locale, I don't believe that has nothing to do though